# Sidekiq worker priority setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, backgroundworker, sidekiq

Currently am running my background jobs using sidekiq. Concurrently am running 10 jobs at a time. These jobs are not a small jobs. It will take 6-8 hours to complete the work.

In the mean time i need to run some smaller jobs(will take 2-3 mins). Currently am not able to run these jobs until any one of the above 10 jobs to complete. So i need to wait for 6-8 hours to perform this small job.

But these jobs should run immediately after adding to the queue. Is there any option to block any one of the process to run this kind of small jobs. I tried the queue option but its also not working in my scenario.

**Here is my sidekiq config**

```
:concurrency: 10
:queues:
  - [web, 7]
  - [default, 3]
```

Can any one give me the solution for this problem?

Comment: You have exactly 10 long jobs?

Comment: @UriAgassi no i have more than 100 long running jobs. My Concurrency is 10.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The long jobs suffocate the smaller jobs since they fight over the same resources.

I can suggest that you run *two* sidekiq processes, each using a different config file, and each listening to a different queue:

`sidekiq_long.yml`:

```
:concurrency: 10
:queues:
  - default
```

`sidekiq_normal.yml`:

```
:concurrency: 3
:queues:
  - web
```

This way one sidekiq process will always be available to server short jobs:

```
sidekiq -C config/sidekiq_long.yml.yml
sidekiq -C config/sidekiq_normal.yml
```

Comment: To run sidekiq without any jobs its taking nearly 300mb of my server memory. so If i run two sidekiq process it will take 600mb. Is there any solution two avoid this issue?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to dedicate a thread to one queue, while using other threads for another queue. You can try writing a wrapper which runs two `Sidekiq::Launcher`s, each with its own configuration, but it does not sound very trivial... do it at your own peril (https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/launcher.rb)

Comment: should we use different log file or same log file when using two processes ?

Comment: The safest way would be to separate the logs. This way you can be sure the processes won't try to write on one another, which might result in broken lines. It is not different than running to identical processes logging to the same file, though, so it is a matter of taste...